Status of J_FILE Field Type for Subforms in Joomla
Hello Joomla Community,
I’m reaching out to clarify the current status of the J_FILE field type in Joomla. Based on my research and discussions, it appears that Joomla has had ongoing issues related to the J_FILE field type, particularly in the context of subforms. I am referencing several related issues and articles:
Joomla Issue #12832 which outlines challenges with file handling.
Component Creator Issue #191 and Issue #128 which also address related problems.
Given these past discussions and reported issues, I would like to confirm if Joomla currently supports a built-in J_FILE field type specifically for subforms. If not, are there any workarounds or updates planned that might address this functionality?
Any insights or updates from the community would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
